# Estimating PDF or TIFF file size before creating it from base64 encoded images

Tags: image, pdf, base64, document, tiff

I have a feeling that this is not doable, but anyway it wouldn't harm to hear more from the great guys @ stackoverflow. We have a module in a system that I'm working on that converts previously scanned papers (**images are saved in the database in base64 format**) to Tiff or PDF file then storing it on the disk. The customer recently requested a feature that allows him to view the PDF or TIFF file size before creating the file on the disk. So, is there any method to estimate the final size of the PDF or Tiff file from only its base64 encoded images?

Comment: Is the actual image file format known beforehand? (Base64 only is a transfer encoding, are the images jpegs? pngs? Something else? )

Comment: @mkl thanks sir for your comment. Yes, the file format is known,  base64 encoded images will be converted into PDF or TIFF files and base64 images were PNGs before encoding

Comment: Hhmmm, if they had been JPEGs, the situation would be simpler: JPEGs can be embedded in PDFs as they are while PNGs are transformed...